# Know if a file from a directory has been modified

Tags: php, directory, fopen, fread

Good day guys..i'm currently working as an sys ad assistant. i just want to know if how can i know that a file from a directory(and it's subdirectory) has been modified..do i need to put every php code on a database? and is there a possibility to know which part of the file has been modified?thanks. please help.

Comment: You could use something like a filesystemwatcher to catch updates, or store md5 file hashes in a database and continually crawl the folder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540339/how-to-check-if-directory-contents-has-changed-with-php

Comment: pass hidden values when file modify.hidden value like date-time and file name to your database.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by the database reference... but in general, if you know a file's creation date, you could check to see if filemtime is different from that.  I'm a bit leery of using file modification times however; I've found some instances in which they were misleading, so take this with a grain of salt.

Outside of having a previous version of the file (via backup or a RCS), I can't think of how you'd see what part was modified.

Comment: Now i  somehow find the answer. and it is by means of bash scripting..thnx for d help anyway.

Comment: Would you mind posting the answer you found as a comment or answer?  Someone might have a similar problem and stumble on this thread, and this could be very valuable to them.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`filemtime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) which will give you the last time that the file was changed.

But you cannot know any made differences as far as you aren't running a version control system.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working as sys ad assistant, I presume you can also use python.
If so, consider using [watchdog](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog) library. I think it is a perfect fit.

When you're at it, you can also use programatically, with python, linux/unix `diff` command.
For this, you can also check out python [sh](http://amoffat.github.com/sh/) module, which enables you to call `diff` from your python code.

php is hardly perfect solution for your sysadmin needs.
And python may be even easier to learn than php.